# Duplicate Javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a javascript countdown in this page:
http://omeumundoptc.comuf.com/countdown/
in the top center left.
I want to duplicate it and place it in the right side.
Note that both countdowns should have different times, so it should have different variables or something.
What would be the steps to do to achieve this?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: so you are wanting to create another counter on top of your iframe or on the original page?

Comment: yes, on the original page.

Comment: I deleted the comment with the address.  You have to look in the counter.js as it searches for the id countbox.  ill look at it more and give an answer

Comment: That's what I thought, but in my knowledge about javascript, I would just create another div for the second countbox and change its id and then change the id in the javascript too, but this doesn't work that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to put this html in the same location as the other counter:

```
<div id="countdown2">
   <div class="event-title">
   </div>
   <div id="countbox2"></div>
   <div class="event-title"></div>
</div>
```

add this to styles.css:

```
#countdown2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 688px;
    top: 290px;
    width: 244px;
    height: 86px;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: #e0d1aa;
}

#countdown2 .event-title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    top: 75px;
    width: 227px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 125%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
}

#countdown2 .days,
#countdown2 .hours, 
#countdown2 .minutes, 
#countdown2 .seconds,
#countdown2 .hundredths {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Monda', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#countdown2 .days {
    left: 14px;
}

#countdown2 .hours {
    left: 71px;
}

#countdown2 .minutes {
    left: 126px;
}

#countdown2 .seconds {
    left: 181px;
}

#countdown2 .hundredths {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    top: 5px;
    left: 218px;
}
```

On the raffle.htm you need to add in your second date in the javascript section like so:

```
//Edit data below to your personal preferences ----------------------------------

//Give the date ---------------------------------
year = 2013; year2 = 2013;
month = 9; month2 = 10;
day = 30; day2 = 30;
//Give the point of time ------------------------
hour= 24; hour2 = 24;
min= 0; min2 = 0;
sec= 0; sec = 0;
//-----------------------------------------------
```

You need to modify your counter.js also with this: (this is far from optimized.  there are much better methods of doing this via jquery)

```
month= --month;
dateFuture = new Date(year,month,day,hour,min,sec);
dateFuture2 = new Date(year2,month2,day2,hour2,min2,sec2);

function GetCount(){

        dateNow = new Date();                                                            
        amount = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime()+5;               
        delete dateNow;

        /* time is already past */
        if(amount < 0){
                out=
                "<div id='days'><span></span><p>0</p><div id='days_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours'><span></span><p>0</p><div id='hours_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='mins'><span></span><p>0</p><div id='mins_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs'><span></span><p>0</p><div id='secs_text'></div></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML=out;       
        }
        /* date is still good */
        else{
                days=0;hours=0;mins=0;secs=0;out="";

                amount = Math.floor(amount/1000); /* kill the milliseconds */

                days=Math.floor(amount/86400); /* days */
                amount=amount%86400;

                hours=Math.floor(amount/3600); /* hours */
                amount=amount%3600;

                mins=Math.floor(amount/60); /* minutes */
                amount=amount%60;


                secs=Math.floor(amount); /* seconds */


                out=
                "<div id='days'><span></span><p>" + days +"</p><div id='days_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours'><span></span><p>" + hours +"</p><div id='hours_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='mins'><span></span><p>" + mins +"</p><div id='mins_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs'><span></span><p>" + secs +"</p><div id='secs_text'></div></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML=out;


                setTimeout("GetCount()", 1000);
        }
}

function GetCount2(){

        dateNow = new Date();                                                            
        amount = dateFuture2.getTime() - dateNow.getTime()+5;               
        delete dateNow;

        /* time is already past */
        if(amount < 0){
                out=
                "<div id='days2'><span></span><p>0</p><div id='days_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours2'><span></span><p>0</p><div id='hours_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='mins2'><span></span><p>0</p><div id='mins_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs2'><span></span><p>0</p><div id='secs_text'></div></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML=out;       
        }
        /* date is still good */
        else{
                days=0;hours=0;mins=0;secs=0;out="";

                amount = Math.floor(amount/1000); /* kill the milliseconds */

                days=Math.floor(amount/86400); /* days */
                amount=amount%86400;

                hours=Math.floor(amount/3600); /* hours */
                amount=amount%3600;

                mins=Math.floor(amount/60); /* minutes */
                amount=amount%60;


                secs=Math.floor(amount); /* seconds */


                out=
                "<div id='days2'><span></span><p>" + days +"</p><div id='days_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours2'><span></span><p>" + hours +"</p><div id='hours_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='mins2'><span></span><p>" + mins +"</p><div id='mins_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs2'><span></span><p>" + secs +"</p><div id='secs_text'></div></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox2').innerHTML=out;


                setTimeout("GetCount2()", 1000);
        }
}

window.onload=function(){GetCount(); GetCount2();}
```

Add this to counter.css:

```
#countbox2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Myriad Pro,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#days2 {
    background-image: url("../images/countdown/flip.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0 7px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 44px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#days_text2 {
    background-image: url("../images/countdown/days_text.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 26px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 44px;
}
#hours2 {
    background-image: url("../images/countdown/flip.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0 7px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 44px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#hours_text2 {
    background-image: url("../images/countdown/hours_text.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 26px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 44px;
}
#mins2 {
    background-image: url("../images/countdown/flip.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0 7px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 44px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#mins_text {
    background-image: url("../images/countdown/mins_text.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 26px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 54px;
}
#secs2 {
    background-image: url("../images/countdown/flip.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0 7px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 44px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#secs_text {
    background-image: url("../images/countdown/secs_text.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 26px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 54px;
}
#days2 p, #hours2 p, #mins2 p, #secs2 p {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: That seems to be it. Thanks.
There's some bad styling though. Actually, I could only see that it is working because I selected the time and copied it and then again to see if there was difference. Can you help place it correctly, please?
Thanks again.

Comment: is it on the website now?

Comment: You added the wrong stuff to countdown.css, you should add that to styles.css and I will make an edit with the stuff to add to countdown.css

Comment: get the extra stuff that I added to the answer for counter.css and I tested it, works fine

Comment: @AlexAlexandre if i answered your question correctly please mark the answer as correct.  Great working with you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
If you want, take a look at my other question, it's about a css dropdown menu, it's having a little problem.